# How my bot can react on the mssages when its mentioned?

Tags: python, discord

I want to add a function on my bot to react the messages when its mentioned.

```
@client.event
        if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Senpai')
            await message.add_reaction(emoji=':thumbsup:')
```

but when I run the function in bot I got
`discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`
the question is why i get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add_reaction() **does not take a discord emoji as an emote**. You need to copy the unicode of the emoji.

#### So ":thumbsup:" is "\U0001F44D"

Here is a [good website to find unicodes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)